# SQL : select 2 consecutive rows with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table event with 3 columns and would like to select two consecutive rows of the same case id with certain criteria (rules) as follows. I have about 5k+ of different case id  to select based on the criteria given and below is just example of 2 case id. I have part of code to try, however, got stuck because i dont know how to select both rows if conditions is met.

Rules:

- If      D1 follows by D3 THEN Select both rows
- IfElse  D1 follows by D4 THEN Select both rows
- IfElse  D2 follows by D1 THEN Select both rows
- IfElse  D2 follows by D3 THEN Select both rows
- IfElse  D3 follows by D2 THEN Select both rows
- IfElse  D3 follows by D1 THEN Select both rows
- Else Do not select

Table event:

```
caseID         D         Timestamp
-----------------------------------
   1           D1           T1
   1           D2           T2
   1           D3           T3
   1           D1           T4
   1           D3           T5
   1           D2           T6
   1           D1           T7
   1           D2           T8
   1           D4           T9
   2           D2           T1
   2           D1           T2
   2           D2           T3
   2           D3           T4
   2           D1           T5
   2           D4           T6
   2           D5           T7
```

Expected output:

```
caseID         D         Timestamp
----------------------------------
   1           D2           T2
   1           D3           T3
   1           D1           T4
   1           D3           T5
   1           D2           T6
   1           D1           T7
   2           D2           T1
   2           D1           T2
   2           D2           T3
   2           D3           T4
   2           D1           T5
   2           D4           T6
```

Code I might try:

```
SELECT caseID, D, Timestamp
FROM event e1
INNER JOIN event e2 ON e1.caseID = e2.caseID
WHERE
    CASE @D
       WHEN e1.D = D1 AND e2.D = D3 THEN ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `lead` and `lag` with `case`:

```
select caseid, d, timestamp
from (
    select *, lead(d) over (partition by caseId order by timestamp) lead, 
              lag(d) over (partition by caseId order by timestamp) lag
    from event
    ) t
where 1 = case 
            when d = 'D1' and lead in ('D3','D4') then 1
            when d = 'D2' and lead in ('D1','D3') then 1
            when d = 'D3' and lead in ('D2','D1') then 1
            when d = 'D1' and lag in ('D2', 'D3') then 1
            when d = 'D2' and lag in ('D3') then 1
            when d = 'D3' and lag in ('D2','D1') then 1
            when d = 'D4' and lag in ('D1') then 1
            else 0
         end 
order by caseid, timestamp
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/TGXV83261)

It could be consolidate, but wanted to be as explicit as possible to define your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `SQL-server 2008` didn't support `Lag` and `Lead` you can write a subquery to make it.

```
SELECT  caseID,
        D,
        Timestamp
FROM (
    select *,(
       select TOP 1 D
       FROM T tt 
       WHERE t1.caseID = tt.caseID 
         and t1.Timestamp < tt.Timestamp
       ORDER BY tt.Timestamp 
    ) nextD,(
       select TOP 1 D
       FROM T tt 
       WHERE t1.caseID = tt.caseID 
         and t1.Timestamp > tt.Timestamp
       ORDER BY tt.Timestamp desc
    ) pervD
    from T t1
) t1
WHERE (CASE WHEN d = 'D1' and nextD in ('D3','D4') OR
                  d = 'D2' and nextD in ('D1','D3') OR
                  d = 'D3' and nextD in ('D2','D1') OR
                  d = 'D1' and pervD in ('D2', 'D3') OR
                  d = 'D2' and pervD in ('D3')      OR
                  d = 'D3' and pervD in ('D2','D1') OR
                  d = 'D4' and pervD in ('D1') 
             THEN D END)  IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cdd289f5967cb6eec08614bb670e46c1)